# How to expand this tables to support revision history

Tags: mysql, revision-history

I have 3 tables:

- **pricelists** (pricelist_id, name)
- **prices** (price_id, pricelist_id, price, note)
- **tickets** (ticket_id, price_id, name, time)

So, the main reason for versioning prices is because prices can be changed in future and I want to keep information about past prices for statistics, and I want to tickets has real price, not future changed price.

Can you please give me some example of queries?

Comment: In pricelists is stored only name of price list, for example, "Prices for concert". In prices are stored data like price: $100 note: adult, another row can be $80 for children and so on. All that prices are attached to pricelist using pricelist_id. Tickets holds data about sold tickets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose one possible approach is making two price tables instead of two: the first one will store some generic price-related data (like 'note' and 'pricelist_id' link, as these won't change with time), and the second one will store the actual prices (along with, probably, timestamps of their activation - but that's not necessary):

```
prices         (price_id, pricelist_id, note)
price_versions (price_ver_id, price_id, price, started_at, ended_at)
tickets        (ticket_id, price_ver_id, name, issued_at)
```

As you see, you refer to `price_versions` in your `tickets` to get the specific price. But you can easily collect the generic price-related information as well (by joining the `prices` table from there).

This approach lets you construct an additional constraint, checking that `issued_at` is not before `started_at` and not after `ended_at` (it that NOT NULL in the corresponding row). But that's an addition, not a requirement, I suppose.